What's the proper way of creating a custom element/web component for tabulator 6.3 using svelte 5?
Tried creating a web component/custom element that would wrap a table from tabulatorjs using svelte, but for some reason can't get the table to properly display. I've followed the docs text and it seems to work works when you're running normal svelte components, but fails as a custom element/component.failing web component
VS
working non web component
For code examples, here's a demo repo containing "main" branch which works and "broken" branch which doesn't.
Also worth noting the counter web component works in both branches, but tabulator fails.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Include all relevant code in the question, do not link to it.

contact the vendor: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues

Alright, first of all thanks for setting up the repo it really helped with figuring it out! You problem is that you're importing the tabulator.min.css file with svelte:head, which doesn't work because of what the documentation explains:

Styles are encapsulated, rather than merely scoped (unless you set shadow: "none"). This means that any non-component styles (such as you might have in a global.css file) will not apply to the custom element, including styles with the :global(...) modifier

If you unminify it and put it inside the style tag you'll basically have a bunch of unused-css-selector warnings that be purged when you build. So the solution is to wrap every single selector with the :global tag so the compiler will let all the style pass through to the dist/assets/main.js where it will encapsulate the table with the appropriate styles. You'll end up with this monstruosity but that works when built — don't forget to add the
<svelte:options customElement="custom-table"/> to the beggining (I removed cause it confuses the REPL). Now, another approach to avoid wrapping every single selector is installing svelte-preprocess and simply opening your style tag like this:
<style global>
/*whole unminified tabulator.min.css*/
</style>

Set it up on your svelte.config.js, which brings me to the last point: When I set up the project Svelte kept complaining about setting customElement: true in the compiler options, which I saw you did inside the vite.config.js' svelte plugin. But the only way Svelte stopped complaining about it was setting it directly in the svelte config, which comes out like this
//svelte.config.js
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import { sveltePreprocess } from 'svelte-preprocess' // optional

export default {
  // moved from vite.config.js
  compilerOptions: {
    customElement: true,
  },
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(), // default preprocess
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess(), // if you want to use Svelte the global style attribute
}

Then you just build it and it works!

Yo! thank you my guy! I ended up going the shadow: "none" route and worked. There was an issue though, first time the table rendered it was an appropriate size, while the next 4-6 times the table expanded horizontally past the page size, BUT i could fix the table size by clicking the top of the table (around the headers). all in all though you pretty much fixed the main issue I was having. thanks again for helping out a js/svelte newbie.

That's awesome, I'm really glad it helped! Remember to place your css fix for that issue inside the style tag and you should be golden. Maybe even just giving the outer div styles to constrain it to its parent size with overflow: auto so you can place the component inside a div whose size you control , or something like that haha
